# Android library (.aar) using the same gradle dependency as app - but different versions, causes a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a Android library which is packaged as an **.aar** file.

My library uses v1.8.0 of Squares Retrofit library internally.

An end user of my library is also using Retrofit, but they are using 2.0.1.

A problem arises when they try and run their app, a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when it reaches a line in my library that calls a Retrofit function that is no longer present in v2.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mylibrary.sdk:mylibrary:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.1'
}
```

I am wondering if there is a standard way of dealing with this this?

The easy options that spring to mind are:

1. We upgrade our Retrofit version to 2
2. The end user downgrades their Retrofit version to 1

Both these options feel to be short-term. Also if for example, we upgrade to Retrofit 2 and a new end-user comes along that is using Retrofit 1, we are back to facing the same problem but in reverse.

Having done some research already, creating a full fat **.aar** build or using shading, may be solutions. If anyone can shed any light on how these can be used in this case it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use a maven repo. In this way you can manage the dependencies excluding some parts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably somewhere else. It's not about the fact that there are some methods missing, because the new (`2.X.X`) version of Retrofit can work side-by-side with the old one (pre `2.0.0`). So if both versions were imported properly into the project, you should be able to use both `Retrofit` and `Retrofit2` without any problems. It's possible because the new version of the library has a different package (`retrofit2.Retrofit` instead of `retrofit.Retrofit`).

Are you sure that your library includes `Retrofit` `1.8.X`? Maybe it just uses methods from the library but the `1.8.X` version is not shipped in your `aar`? That would actually explain a lot.

What you can is either:

- Ask the person that is using your library to include both versions of the `Retrofit`, apart from your library.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
```

or

- Make sure the proper version of the `Retrofit` (`1.X.X`) is included in your library's `aar`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response. It turns out the end-user was actually still using the retrofit 2 beta - 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2', which was before the package name was changed to 'retrofit2'. I've asked them to upgrade to the production release which has solved the problem.